# Constructing a python loop statement

Tags: python, function, loops, while-loop

I am new to programming and have been battling to solve a problem for 3 days now. Help would really be appreciated!! I have built a rock/paper/scissors game and it works fine except for 1 thing: When P2 (Player 2) enters something other than r/p/s, the program tells it the input is invalid, but then jumps back to P1 (Player 1) for input - I want it to carry on at P2, not start at P1 again. Now I know there are probable 100 ways to better write the program, but I want to fix it using my current code - I am guessing with another while loop or something, but have tried endless options and combinations withou success. Someone please help?

```
def rps():
    if p1 == 'r' and p2 == 's':
        print('Congrats P1! ')
    elif p1 == 'r' and p2 == 'p':
        print('Congrats P2! ')
    elif p1 == 'p' and p2 == 's':
        print('Congrats P2! ')
    elif p1 == 'p' and p2 == 'r':
        print('Congrats P1! ')
    elif p1 == 's' and p2 == 'r':
        print('Congrats P2! ')
    elif p1 == 's' and p2 == 'p':
        print('Congrats P1! ')
    elif p1 == 'r' and p2 == 'r':
        print('Draw! ')
    elif p1 == 's' and p2 == 's':
        print('Draw! ')
    elif p1 == 'p' and p2 == 'p':
        print('Draw! ')

while True:
    p1 = input('Choice P1? r/p/s (Type "quit" to exit)')
    p1check = p1 == 'r' or p1 == 'p' or p1 == 's'
    if p1 == 'quit':
        print('Bye!')
        break
    elif p1check is False:
        print('Invalid choice P1! ')
        continue

    p2 = input('Choice P2? r/p/s (type "quit" to exit)')
    p2check = p2 == 'r' or p2 == 'p' or p2 == 's'
    if p2 == 'quit':
        print('Chow!!')
        break
    elif p2check is False:
        print('Invalid choice P2! ')
        continue

    rps()
```

Comment: Look into the use of functions and how they can help you in this situation. Specifically, you should be calling a function that asks for input when the input is invalid (i.e. call the function in your `elif` clause)

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to the wonderful world of programming :)

You are not far from the expected result, I suggest you to add a loop that will run until P2 input is valid.

```
#this is to avoid a while true and a break instruction
play_the_game = true

while play_the_game:
    #I skip the P1 managing part for more readability

    p2check = false
    #Loop until the player 2 entries match the expected inputs
    while p2check == false:
        p2 = input('Choice P2? r/p/s (type "quit" to exit)')
        p2check = p2 == 'r' or p2 == 'p' or p2 == 's'
        if p2 == 'quit':
            print('Chow!!')
            #play_the_game is now false, the main loop will exit.
            play_the_game = false
            #I added 'p2check = true' to make sure the loop 'while p2check == false:' will exit.
            #You can use a break instruction instead of 'p2check = true' if you prefer
            p2check = true
        elif p2check is False:
            print('Invalid choice P2! ')
```

Comment: Hi Cid, thanks for the reply, much appreciated!! Not at work today, will check it out this weekend, but looks good, will loop back to P2's input like I wanted, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, I added some lines for the 'quit' case because I noticed a bug that will occure when you type 'quit' (`while p2check == false:` won't exit)

Comment: Great, thanks Cid, will check it out a bit later, busy downloading Anaconda!  :-)

Answer (score -1):

What I'd recommend is placing the input in a loop.

```
import sys
p2 = ""
while p2 != 'r' or p2 != 'p' or p2 != 's' or p2 != 'quit'
    p2 = input('Choice P2? r/p/s (type "quit" to exit)')
if p2 == 'quit':
    #Handle quite logic
    sys.exit(0)
```

This is considered a `Do While` loop in other languages. The loop gets entered on the first go due to `p2` being an `empty string`. Then if the user enters a CORRECT input the loop will break, otherwise it will keep asking for input.

What you have now just continues the loop without asking for second input.

Comment: Thanks ltd, will check it out, appreciate it!!